# PHP array with datetime function to get time in seconds

Tags: php, python, codeigniter

I have already wrote this function in python (as I have much solid knowledge there), but I need to use this function in PHP (on some codeigniter project - model). So my question is how the fallowing function will look on PHP:

```html
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
def getMaxValVerify(myList):
    intervalTime = myList[len(myList) -1][1] -  myList[0][1]
    seconds=timedelta.total_seconds(intervalTime)
    return seconds
```

Now to explain what it does, for a list(array) that looks like this :

```html
list = [(41740, datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 20, 18, 00, 00)), (41280, datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 20, 18, 00, 30)), (40500, datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 20, 18, 02, 00))]
```

It will return the difference in seconds from the first datetime element to the last, in our case from 18:00:00 to 18:02:00 will return:

```html
print getMaxValVerify(list)

120.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the DateTime class in PHP, which gives you access to DateIntervals.

Example for 2 dates :

```
<?php
$dateStart = new DateTime('2016-06-20 18:00:00');
$interval= $dateStart->diff(new DateTime('2016-06-20 18:30:00'));
echo $interval->s.' seconds';
```

Function example :

```
<?php
function getInterval($list) // Although you should use 2 parameters instead
{
    $dateStartList = min($list);
    $dateEndList = max($list);

    $dateStart = new DateTime(dateStartList);
    $interval= $dateStart->diff(new DateTime($dateEndList));
    return $interval->s
}

echo getInterval('2016-06-20 18:00:00', '2016-06-20 17:20:00', '2016-06-20 18:30:00') . ' seconds';
```

Comment: Your function will output the diff between first and second element in a list, I will have random arrays, and I will need to calculate between first and last!

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood. Answer updated. You can use `min()` and `max()` functions

Comment: Good, now it looks fine I think, thanks a lot, I will test it.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this has already been answered, but here's an alternate way to do the a similar thing with PHP - the only difference is that this is the 'procedural' method versus the 'object-oriented' method.. which uses `strtotime` instead of the `DateTime` object

```
 <?php  
       function get_inerval($inputDateTimes) {
            $epochTimes = array_map('strtotime', $inputDateTimes);
            $startDateTime = min($epochTimes);
            $endDateTime = max($epochTimes);
            return round((($endDateTime - $startDateTime) * .001),1);
       }

      $inputs = array('2016-06-20 18:00:00', '2016-06-20 17:20:00', '2016-06-20 18:30:00');

      $result = get_interval($inputs);

      print_r($result);   // returns 120.0


   ?>
```